# Notion of "smoothly isotopic to the identity"

Tags: general-topology, definition, differential-topology

I have some trouble understanding the notion of "smoothly isotopic to the identity". I am working on the following proof: "Any orientation preserving diffeo. $f$ of $\Bbb R^m$ is smoothly isotopic to the identity". I don't understand, what I have to show here. Many thanks for help.

Comment: You have to find a smooth map $H:\Bbb R^m\times [0,1]\to \Bbb R^m$ such that $H(x,0)=f(x),\ H(x,1)=x$ for all $x\in \Bbb R^m$ such that for each $t\in [0,1]$ the map $H_t:\Bbb R^m\to \Bbb R^m$ defined by $H_t(x):=H(x,t)$ for all $x\in \Bbb R^m$ is a diffeomorphism.

Comment: So, consider $H(x,t):=(1-t)f(x)+tx$ for all $(x,t)\in \Bbb R^m\times [0,1]$.